# slack python api delete message

Tags: python, bots, slack-api

I am trying to use my bot to delete certain messages in a slack channel with this api call

```
    import os
    import time
    import re
    from slackclient import SlackClient

    slack_client = SlackClient(
     'xsssssseeeeeeee')

   slack_mute_bot_id = None


   def delete_message(slack_event):
    for event in slack_event:
        if event["type"] == "message":
            message_text = event['text']
            time_stamp = event['ts']
            channel_id = event['channel']
            slack_client.api_call(
                'chat.delete',
                channel=channel_id,
                ts=time_stamp,
                as_user=True
            )
            print(message_text + " delted")    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if slack_client.rtm_connect(with_team_state=False):
        slack_mute_bot_id = slack_client.api_call("auth.test")["user_id"]
        while True:
            # print(slack_client.rtm_read())
            delete_message(slack_client.rtm_read())

            time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("Connection failed. Exception traceback printed above.")
```

I do not get any error message after doing this and the bot does not delete the message. I am using the bot user token. I have benn able to send message succesfully but the delete method does not work and still gives np responses

Comment: The bot token will only allow you to delete messages from your bot. If you want to be able to delete messages from other users, you need a user token from an admin. see also https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete

Comment: yes i finally was able to delete using the url call but not the bot api call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer - https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete

- When used with a user token, this method may only delete messages
  that user themselves can delete in Slack.
- When used with a bot token, this method may delete only messages
  posted by that bot.

I got stumbled into the same thing.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the bot message sent as a direct message?